# Get-PnPTenant is throwing unauthorized error

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online, pnp.powershell

We are using the Connect-PnPOnline, to connect with sharepoint using the CBA(application Id and secret). And the app has the necessary permissions and SharePoint admin role too.
image

[image]

While running the Get-PnPTenant it is giving the following error:
image

[image]

can somebody please help us why this is happening.

Thanks

Comment: You are connecting to the server but you do not have the authorization to access the data.  You need to setup the proper authorization on the server,  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent?pivots=portal

Comment: @jdweng, I had given the necessary consent to the application. But still it is giving this error

Comment: See Next-Steps at bottom of the link.